# Concurrent READ causing StaleObjectStateException during a DELETE?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

On our web site we have two operations which work against the same table, one does a read of multiple rows and the other deletes a row.

We're using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 3.6.

The exact operations are

```
EntityManager.createQuery().getResultList();
```

and

```
EntityManager.remove();
```

We are getting the StaleObjectStateException on the remove() thread, not on the getResultList() thread.   The question is, why would a read cause a StaleObjectException?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Are you certain there is no way you are modifying any entities after you retrieve them?  Maybe there is some kind of side effecting going on?  You should try just running the read operation in isolation and then checking to see if the @Version annotated column is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause of this problem turned out to be completely unrelated to Hibernate or Spring, it was an HTML/Javascript problem that was causing two separate HTTP requests to be sent every time the link in question was clicked.   (Both requests were edits, so that was the source of the conflict.)

Just putting this answer out here so that people will know that Spring and Hibernate DO work.

Answer (score 0):

Like Pace says, may be you are modifying some instace retrieved with that query while the instace still attached, it means before the persistenceContext ("instance" of the EntityManager), within the instance attached, commit the transaction.

An other possible thing is that you are overwriting the value of the version's attribute, so the entityManager not only mark the instances/entities as modified but it also execute an update query with a lower/not espected version value.

Regards